# How to follow a link in a get request header in Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, pagination

I am trying to retrieve paginated results from a 3rd party API after making an API call from my Node.js/Express server. I then want to send the data through to the client. I can retrieve the first page of results using the Request package and the following code:

```
var options = {
  url: `https://theURL.com`,
  headers: {
    'authorization': `bearer ${user_token}`,
    'user-agent': '***my details***'
  }
}

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
    res.json({
      data: body
  });
  } else {
    res.send("an error occured")
  }
}

Request(options, callback);
```

I understand that the response will contain a Link header which I should follow to get the next page's data and to retrieve the link header for the page after that. I repeat this process until I reach a blank link header, at which point all the pages of data have been retrieved.

Firstly, I don't know how to approach this task, should I be following all the link headers and compiling all the results on my server before transferring them to the client? Or should I send each pages worth of data to the client as I get it and then deal with it there?

Secondly, how can an appropriate solution be achieved in code?

Comment: Since each page is referenced by its predecessor (hence forcing sequential calls), fetching everything before sending data might result in a timeout for your client. Here I would use sockets to push data to the client as they come, without the client needing to re-send a request. And you can handle each socket events (more data / no more data) transparently for the user on the client side. But that means implementing sockets, which could imply some reading/learning first if you're not familiar with these.